# Unable to Link Intel MKL 11.3 libraries with Eigen 3.2.9 TDM-GCC-5.1.0 Win64

Tags: c++, eigen, intel-mkl, win64, mingw-w64

I am trying to link `Intel MKL 11.3` library with `Eigen3.2.9` using `TDM-GCC-5.1.0` in `Win64` environment.

I am using the following definitions:

```
#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL
-DMKL_LP64
```

and linking with the `...\lib\intel64_win\*.lib` libraries with `LP64`.
(Note `ILP64` gives incompatible integer errors with `Eigen`)

But I get the following error:

```
...\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_rt.lib: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
```

Answer (score 0):

Eigen only supports MKL with LP64 model. MKL supports LP64 and ILP64. Win64 is neither of them. Win64 is LLP64.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

According to MKL link line advisor, TDM-GCC is not officially supported on Windows platform.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor

The `.lib` format for VS may not be compatible with cygwin gcc.